# I can't figure out how to get this text under the text before it

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get this text, `#contact`, to show up below the main title of the page. But it is just showing up at the top, I have tried with and without the align function.

Here's the code.

```css
        body.navbartext, html{
        margin:0px;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        font-family:helvetica;
        height:1080px;
    }

    ul.navbartext{
        list-style:none;
        padding:5px;
        display: block;
        width:100%;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 40px #ccc;
        margin:0px;
    }

    a.navbartext{
        text-decoration: none;
        font-size:15px;
        color: black;
    }

    li.navbartext{
        display:inline-block;
        margin: 10px;
    }

    div.mainpagetitle{
        height: 200px;
        width: 400px;
        background: black;
        position: fixed;
        top:50%;
        left: 50%;
        margin-top: -100px;
        margin-left: -200px;
    }

    body.mainpagetitle{
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    h1.mainpagetitle{
        font-size: 4em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: helvetica;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }

    #subtitle {
        font-size: 2em;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: center;
        font-family: Roboto;
        position: absolute;
        top: 59%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    }

    #contact {
        top: 0%;
    }
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="navbartext">
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Youtube</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Github</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Roblox</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <header>
    <h1 class="mainpagetitle">Web Dev, Game Dev</h1>
    <h2 id="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
  </header>
    <div id="contact"><a href="contact">Contact Info</a></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I've tried in a snippet, it's showing in the middle of the page. did you try to remove align="right" from contact div?

Comment: You have two bodies in your HTML never seen that in my life, pretty sure that is not right HTML syntax to begin with...

Comment: @mbkfa93 Yes, I tried removing the align right and center. Still doesn't work. And also, I keep adding bodies by habit, since I'm pretty new.

Comment: You need to post your CSS also. Make [mre]... And you can have only ONE body per page...

Comment: Added the CSS..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *can*  replace the `top: 0%` of `#contact` (which has no effect whatsoever, since `position` is neither absolute nor fixed or relative) with `margin-top: 60%;` or any value that suits you. That moves it below the absolutely positioned elements, which are *not*  part of the document flow and therefore can overlap other elements.

However, it really doesn't make sense to use absolutely positioned elements the way you do it. You should arrange your code in a different way in general (i.e. *not* using those absolute positions)

```css
body.navbartext,
html {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  font-family: helvetica;
  height: 1080px;
}

ul.navbartext {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 5px;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  box-shadow: 1px 2px 40px #ccc;
  margin: 0px;
}

a.navbartext {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: black;
}

li.navbartext {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

div.mainpagetitle {
  height: 200px;
  width: 400px;
  background: black;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-top: -100px;
  margin-left: -200px;
}

body.mainpagetitle {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

h1.mainpagetitle {
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: helvetica;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#subtitle {
  font-size: 2em;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Roboto;
  position: absolute;
  top: 59%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

#contact {
  margin-top: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul class="navbartext">
    <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Home</a></li>
    <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Youtube</a></li>
    <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Github</a></li>
    <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Roblox</a></li>
    <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<header>
  <h1 class="mainpagetitle">Web Dev, Game Dev</h1>
  <h2 id="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
</header>
<div id="contact"><a href="contact">Contact Info</a></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. Note that there should only be a single body tag in your HTML markup

```html
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="navbartext">
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Home</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Youtube</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Github</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="">Roblox</a></li>
      <li class="navbartext"><a class="navbartext" href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <header>
    <h1 class="mainpagetitle">Web Dev, Game Dev</h1>
    <h2 id="subtitle">Subtitle</h2>
    <div id="contact"><a href="contact">Contact Info</a></div>
  </header>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I tried this and it just shows up at the top right corner, instead of below the Web Dev, Game Dev thing.